# What's the best way to split the letter and number sections from a string?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a string `"AB12"`, what's the best (least cumbersome) way to grab the two parts `"AB"` and `"12"`.

Other valid strings to split could be `"A1"`, `"AA1"`, `"A12"`. This is for a JavaScript spreadsheet application, hence the strings always relate to spreadsheet ranges.

Comment: How is "AA" part of a string "AB12"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var parts= "AA1".match(/([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)/);

#parts[1] = AA
#parts[2] = 1
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, wasn't sure on how to get sub pattern matches. Thanks.

Comment: @Brandon Wamoldt you mean #parts[0] = AA and parts[1]=1. Right?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy nope, [0] is the full string "AA1"

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use match method

Take letters:

```
console.log("hello 345".match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).join(''))
```

Take String:

```
console.log("hello 345".match(/[0-9]/g).join(''))
```

http://jsbin.com/IvIFEWo/1/edit